# How is STARTUPINFO from CreateProcessW used in RtlCreateUserProcess?

Tags: windows, winapi

How is `STARTUPINFO` in `CreateProcessW` used in the call to `RtlCreateUserProcess`? Can someone explain more about this?

I know that `PROCESS_INFORMATION` in `CreateProcessW` is used by `RtlCreateUserProcess` as `RTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION`. But where is the data from `STARTUPINFO` in `CreateProcessW` used when the call to `RtlCreateUserProcess` is made?

I tried debugging, but it's such a long way from `CreateProcessW` to `RtlCreateUserProcess`.

Comment: https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/proc.c

Comment: I know very little about `RtlCreateUserProcess`. But I know something on `NtCreateUserProcess`  about parent process spoofing to create processes.https://gist.github.com/Torrecto/70e6a0963021db2853755840feaa9065.
Is that helpful?

Comment: @Torrecto - MSFT: Thank you for that code example. Ill have a look at it.

Comment: @JochenVanAelten Any updates? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes i think it is .. PS_ATTRIBUTE list is used in NtCreateUserProcess for what InitializeProcThreadAttributeList & UpdateProcThreadAttribute normally do for CreateProcessW using the updated STARTUPINFOEXW. So yeah i think i found it. :)

Comment: @JochenVanAelten Glad to hear it. I'll convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

OP was looking for `PS_ATTRIBUTE` list is used in `NtCreateUserProcess` for what `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList` & `UpdateProcThreadAttribute` normally do for `CreateProcessW` using the updated `STARTUPINFOEXW`.

This is main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>
#include"rtheader.h"
int main()
{
    // Path to the image file from which the process will be created
    UNICODE_STRING NtImagePath, Params, ImagePath;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&ImagePath, (PWSTR)L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&NtImagePath, (PWSTR)L"\\??\\C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&Params, (PWSTR)L"\"C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\cmd.exe\" /k echo Hello world!");
    // Create the process parameters
    PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters = NULL;
    RtlCreateProcessParametersEx(&ProcessParameters, &ImagePath, NULL, NULL, &Params, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS_NORMALIZED);

    // Initialize the PS_CREATE_INFO structure
    PS_CREATE_INFO CreateInfo = { 0 };
    CreateInfo.Size = sizeof(CreateInfo);
    CreateInfo.State = PsCreateInitialState;

    //Skip Image File Execution Options debugger
    CreateInfo.InitState.u1.InitFlags = PsSkipIFEODebugger;

    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objAttr = { sizeof(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES) };
    PPS_STD_HANDLE_INFO stdHandleInfo = (PPS_STD_HANDLE_INFO)RtlAllocateHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(PS_STD_HANDLE_INFO));
    PCLIENT_ID clientId = (PCLIENT_ID)RtlAllocateHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE));
    PSECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION SecImgInfo = (PSECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION)RtlAllocateHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION));
    PPS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST AttributeList = (PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST*)RtlAllocateHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST));

    // Create necessary attributes
    AttributeList->TotalLength = sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST);
    AttributeList->Attributes[0].Attribute = PS_ATTRIBUTE_CLIENT_ID;
    AttributeList->Attributes[0].Size = sizeof(CLIENT_ID);
    AttributeList->Attributes[0].ValuePtr = clientId;

    AttributeList->Attributes[1].Attribute = PS_ATTRIBUTE_IMAGE_INFO;
    AttributeList->Attributes[1].Size = sizeof(SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION);
    AttributeList->Attributes[1].ValuePtr = SecImgInfo;

    AttributeList->Attributes[2].Attribute = PS_ATTRIBUTE_IMAGE_NAME;
    AttributeList->Attributes[2].Size = NtImagePath.Length;
    AttributeList->Attributes[2].ValuePtr = NtImagePath.Buffer;

    AttributeList->Attributes[3].Attribute = PS_ATTRIBUTE_STD_HANDLE_INFO;
    AttributeList->Attributes[3].Size = sizeof(PS_STD_HANDLE_INFO);
    AttributeList->Attributes[3].ValuePtr = stdHandleInfo;

    DWORD64 policy = PROCESS_CREATION_MITIGATION_POLICY_BLOCK_NON_MICROSOFT_BINARIES_ALWAYS_ON;

    // Add process mitigation attribute
    AttributeList->Attributes[4].Attribute = PS_ATTRIBUTE_MITIGATION_OPTIONS;
    AttributeList->Attributes[4].Size = sizeof(DWORD64);
    AttributeList->Attributes[4].ValuePtr = &policy;

    // Spoof Parent Process Id as explorer.exe
    DWORD trayPID;
    HWND trayWnd = FindWindowW(L"Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(trayWnd, &trayPID);
    HANDLE hParent = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, trayPID);
    if (hParent)
    {
        AttributeList->Attributes[5].Attribute = PS_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS;
        AttributeList->Attributes[5].Size = sizeof(HANDLE);
        AttributeList->Attributes[5].ValuePtr = hParent;
    }
    else
    {
        AttributeList->TotalLength -= sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE);
    }
    // Create the process
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL, hThread = NULL;
    NtCreateUserProcess(&hProcess, &hThread, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, &objAttr, &objAttr, 0, 0, ProcessParameters, &CreateInfo, AttributeList);

    // Clean up
    if (hParent) CloseHandle(hParent);
    RtlFreeHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), 0, AttributeList);
    RtlFreeHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), 0, stdHandleInfo);
    RtlFreeHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), 0, clientId);
    RtlFreeHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), 0, SecImgInfo);
    RtlDestroyProcessParameters(ProcessParameters);
}
```

This is header:

```
 #pragma once
    #pragma comment( lib, "ntdll" )
    #include <Windows.h>
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"
    {
    #endif
        typedef enum _PS_ATTRIBUTE_NUM
        {
            PsAttributeParentProcess, // in HANDLE
            PsAttributeDebugObject, // in HANDLE
            PsAttributeToken, // in HANDLE
            PsAttributeClientId, // out PCLIENT_ID
            PsAttributeTebAddress, // out PTEB *
            PsAttributeImageName, // in PWSTR
            PsAttributeImageInfo, // out PSECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION
            PsAttributeMemoryReserve, // in PPS_MEMORY_RESERVE
            PsAttributePriorityClass, // in UCHAR
            PsAttributeErrorMode, // in ULONG
            PsAttributeStdHandleInfo, // 10, in PPS_STD_HANDLE_INFO
            PsAttributeHandleList, // in HANDLE[]
            PsAttributeGroupAffinity, // in PGROUP_AFFINITY
            PsAttributePreferredNode, // in PUSHORT
            PsAttributeIdealProcessor, // in PPROCESSOR_NUMBER
            PsAttributeUmsThread, // ? in PUMS_CREATE_THREAD_ATTRIBUTES
            PsAttributeMitigationOptions, // in PPS_MITIGATION_OPTIONS_MAP (PROCESS_CREATION_MITIGATION_POLICY_*) // since WIN8
            PsAttributeProtectionLevel, // in PS_PROTECTION // since WINBLUE
            PsAttributeSecureProcess, // in PPS_TRUSTLET_CREATE_ATTRIBUTES, since THRESHOLD
            PsAttributeJobList, // in HANDLE[]
            PsAttributeChildProcessPolicy, // 20, in PULONG (PROCESS_CREATION_CHILD_PROCESS_*) // since THRESHOLD2
            PsAttributeAllApplicationPackagesPolicy, // in PULONG (PROCESS_CREATION_ALL_APPLICATION_PACKAGES_*) // since REDSTONE
            PsAttributeWin32kFilter, // in PWIN32K_SYSCALL_FILTER
            PsAttributeSafeOpenPromptOriginClaim, // in
            PsAttributeBnoIsolation, // in PPS_BNO_ISOLATION_PARAMETERS // since REDSTONE2
            PsAttributeDesktopAppPolicy, // in PULONG (PROCESS_CREATION_DESKTOP_APP_*)
            PsAttributeChpe, // in BOOLEAN // since REDSTONE3
            PsAttributeMitigationAuditOptions, // in PPS_MITIGATION_AUDIT_OPTIONS_MAP (PROCESS_CREATION_MITIGATION_AUDIT_POLICY_*) // since 21H1
            PsAttributeMachineType, // in WORD // since 21H2
            PsAttributeComponentFilter,
            PsAttributeEnableOptionalXStateFeatures, // since WIN11
            PsAttributeMax
        } PS_ATTRIBUTE_NUM;
    
    #define RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS_NORMALIZED              0x01
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER_MASK    0x0000ffff
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_THREAD         0x00010000 // Attribute may be used with thread creation
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_INPUT          0x00020000 // Attribute is input only
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_ADDITIVE       0x00040000 // Attribute may be "accumulated", e.g. bitmasks, counters, etc.
    
    #define PsAttributeValue(Number, Thread, Input, Additive) \
        (((Number) & PS_ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER_MASK) | \
        ((Thread) ? PS_ATTRIBUTE_THREAD : 0) | \
        ((Input) ? PS_ATTRIBUTE_INPUT : 0) | \
        ((Additive) ? PS_ATTRIBUTE_ADDITIVE : 0))
    
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeParentProcess, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE) // 0x60000
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_OBJECT \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeDebugObject, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE) // 0x60001
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_TOKEN \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeToken, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE) // 0x60002
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_CLIENT_ID \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeClientId, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) // 0x10003
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_TEB_ADDRESS \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeTebAddress, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) // 0x10004
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_IMAGE_NAME \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeImageName, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20005
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_IMAGE_INFO \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeImageInfo, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE) // 0x6
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_MEMORY_RESERVE \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeMemoryReserve, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20007
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_PRIORITY_CLASS \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributePriorityClass, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20008
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_ERROR_MODE \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeErrorMode, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20009
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_STD_HANDLE_INFO \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeStdHandleInfo, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x2000A
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeHandleList, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x2000B
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_AFFINITY \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeGroupAffinity, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x2000C
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_PREFERRED_NODE \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributePreferredNode, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x2000D
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_IDEAL_PROCESSOR \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeIdealProcessor, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x2000E
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_MITIGATION_OPTIONS \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeMitigationOptions, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x60010
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_PROTECTION_LEVEL \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeProtectionLevel, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20011
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_SECURE_PROCESS \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeSecureProcess, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20012
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_JOB_LIST \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeJobList, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20013
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_CHILD_PROCESS_POLICY \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeChildProcessPolicy, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20014
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_ALL_APPLICATION_PACKAGES_POLICY \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeAllApplicationPackagesPolicy, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20015
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_WIN32K_FILTER \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeWin32kFilter, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20016
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_SAFE_OPEN_PROMPT_ORIGIN_CLAIM \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeSafeOpenPromptOriginClaim, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20017
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_BNO_ISOLATION \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeBnoIsolation, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20018
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_DESKTOP_APP_POLICY \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeDesktopAppPolicy, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x20019
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_CHPE \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeChpe, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE) // 0x6001A
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_MITIGATION_AUDIT_OPTIONS \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeMitigationAuditOptions, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x2001B
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_MACHINE_TYPE \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeMachineType, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE) // 0x6001C
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_COMPONENT_FILTER \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeComponentFilter, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x2001D
    #define PS_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_OPTIONAL_XSTATE_FEATURES \
        PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeEnableOptionalXStateFeatures, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE) // 0x3001E
    
        typedef struct _PS_ATTRIBUTE
        {
            ULONG_PTR Attribute;                // PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_XXX | PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_XXX modifiers, see ProcThreadAttributeValue macro and Windows Internals 6 (372)
            SIZE_T Size;                        // Size of Value or *ValuePtr
            union
            {
                ULONG_PTR Value;                // Reserve 8 bytes for data (such as a Handle or a data pointer)
                PVOID ValuePtr;                 // data pointer
            };
            PSIZE_T ReturnLength;               // Either 0 or specifies size of data returned to caller via "ValuePtr"
        } PS_ATTRIBUTE, * PPS_ATTRIBUTE;
    
        typedef enum _PS_IFEO_KEY_STATE
        {
            PsReadIFEOAllValues,
            PsSkipIFEODebugger,
            PsSkipAllIFEO,
            PsMaxIFEOKeyStates
        } PS_IFEO_KEY_STATE, * PPS_IFEO_KEY_STATE;
    
        typedef enum _PS_CREATE_STATE
        {
            PsCreateInitialState,
            PsCreateFailOnFileOpen,
            PsCreateFailOnSectionCreate,
            PsCreateFailExeFormat,
            PsCreateFailMachineMismatch,
            PsCreateFailExeName, // Debugger specified
            PsCreateSuccess,
            PsCreateMaximumStates
        } PS_CREATE_STATE;
    
        typedef struct _PS_CREATE_INFO
        {
            SIZE_T Size;
            PS_CREATE_STATE State;
            union
            {
                // PsCreateInitialState
                struct
                {
                    union
                    {
                        ULONG InitFlags;
                        struct
                        {
                            UCHAR WriteOutputOnExit : 1;
                            UCHAR DetectManifest : 1;
                            UCHAR IFEOSkipDebugger : 1;
                            UCHAR IFEODoNotPropagateKeyState : 1;
                            UCHAR SpareBits1 : 4;
                            UCHAR SpareBits2 : 8;
                            USHORT ProhibitedImageCharacteristics : 16;
                        } s1;
                    } u1;
                    ACCESS_MASK AdditionalFileAccess;
                } InitState;
    
                // PsCreateFailOnSectionCreate
                struct
                {
                    HANDLE FileHandle;
                } FailSection;
    
                // PsCreateFailExeFormat
                struct
                {
                    USHORT DllCharacteristics;
                } ExeFormat;
    
                // PsCreateFailExeName
                struct
                {
                    HANDLE IFEOKey;
                } ExeName;
    
                // PsCreateSuccess
                struct
                {
                    union
                    {
                        ULONG OutputFlags;
                        struct
                        {
                            UCHAR ProtectedProcess : 1;
                            UCHAR AddressSpaceOverride : 1;
                            UCHAR DevOverrideEnabled : 1; // From Image File Execution Options
                            UCHAR ManifestDetected : 1;
                            UCHAR ProtectedProcessLight : 1;
                            UCHAR SpareBits1 : 3;
                            UCHAR SpareBits2 : 8;
                            USHORT SpareBits3 : 16;
                        } s2;
                    } u2;
                    HANDLE FileHandle;
                    HANDLE SectionHandle;
                    ULONGLONG UserProcessParametersNative;
                    ULONG UserProcessParametersWow64;
                    ULONG CurrentParameterFlags;
                    ULONGLONG PebAddressNative;
                    ULONG PebAddressWow64;
                    ULONGLONG ManifestAddress;
                    ULONG ManifestSize;
                } SuccessState;
            };
        } PS_CREATE_INFO, * PPS_CREATE_INFO;
        typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING
        {
            USHORT Length;
            USHORT MaximumLength;
            PWSTR Buffer;
        } UNICODE_STRING, * PUNICODE_STRING;
        typedef const UNICODE_STRING* PCUNICODE_STRING;
        typedef struct _PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST
        {
            SIZE_T TotalLength;                 // sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)
            PS_ATTRIBUTE Attributes[6];         // Depends on how many attribute entries should be supplied to NtCreateUserProcess
        } PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST, * PPS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST;
        typedef struct _CURDIR
        {
            UNICODE_STRING DosPath;
            HANDLE Handle;
        } CURDIR, * PCURDIR;
        typedef struct _RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR
        {
            USHORT Flags;
            USHORT Length;
            ULONG TimeStamp;
            UNICODE_STRING DosPath;
        } RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR, * PRTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR;
    
    #define RTL_MAX_DRIVE_LETTERS 32
        typedef struct _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS
        {
            ULONG MaximumLength;
            ULONG Length;
    
            ULONG Flags;
            ULONG DebugFlags;
    
            HANDLE ConsoleHandle;
            ULONG ConsoleFlags;
            HANDLE StandardInput;
            HANDLE StandardOutput;
            HANDLE StandardError;
    
            CURDIR CurrentDirectory;
            UNICODE_STRING DllPath;
            UNICODE_STRING ImagePathName;
            UNICODE_STRING CommandLine;
            PWCHAR Environment;
    
            ULONG StartingX;
            ULONG StartingY;
            ULONG CountX;
            ULONG CountY;
            ULONG CountCharsX;
            ULONG CountCharsY;
            ULONG FillAttribute;
    
            ULONG WindowFlags;
            ULONG ShowWindowFlags;
            UNICODE_STRING WindowTitle;
            UNICODE_STRING DesktopInfo;
            UNICODE_STRING ShellInfo;
            UNICODE_STRING RuntimeData;
            RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR CurrentDirectories[RTL_MAX_DRIVE_LETTERS];
    
            ULONG_PTR EnvironmentSize;
            ULONG_PTR EnvironmentVersion;
            PVOID PackageDependencyData;
            ULONG ProcessGroupId;
            ULONG LoaderThreads;
        } RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS, * PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS;
        typedef struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            ULONG Length;
            HANDLE RootDirectory;
            PUNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
            ULONG Attributes;
            PVOID SecurityDescriptor;
            PVOID SecurityQualityOfService;
        } OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, * POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;
        NTSYSAPI
            NTSTATUS
            NTAPI
            RtlDestroyProcessParameters(PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters);
    
        NTSYSAPI
            BOOLEAN
            NTAPI
            RtlFreeHeap(PVOID HeapHandle, ULONG Flags, PVOID BaseAddress);
    
        NTSYSAPI
            VOID
            NTAPI
            RtlInitUnicodeString(PUNICODE_STRING DestinationString, PWSTR SourceString);
        NTSYSAPI
            NTSTATUS
            NTAPI
            RtlCreateProcessParametersEx(
                PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS* pProcessParameters,
                PUNICODE_STRING ImagePathName,
                PUNICODE_STRING DllPath,
                PUNICODE_STRING CurrentDirectory,
                PUNICODE_STRING CommandLine,
                PVOID Environment,
                PUNICODE_STRING WindowTitle,
                PUNICODE_STRING DesktopInfo,
                PUNICODE_STRING ShellInfo,
                PUNICODE_STRING RuntimeData,
                ULONG Flags
            );
        NTSYSCALLAPI
            NTSTATUS
            NTAPI
            NtCreateUserProcess(
                _Out_ PHANDLE ProcessHandle,
                _Out_ PHANDLE ThreadHandle,
                _In_ ACCESS_MASK ProcessDesiredAccess,
                _In_ ACCESS_MASK ThreadDesiredAccess,
                _In_opt_ POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ProcessObjectAttributes,
                _In_opt_ POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ThreadObjectAttributes,
                _In_ ULONG ProcessFlags,
                _In_ ULONG ThreadFlags,
                _In_ PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters,
                _Inout_ PPS_CREATE_INFO CreateInfo,
                _In_ PPS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST AttributeList
            );
    
        NTSYSAPI
            PVOID
            NTAPI
            RtlAllocateHeap(
                _In_ PVOID HeapHandle,
                _In_opt_ ULONG Flags,
                _In_ SIZE_T Size
            );
    
        typedef struct _PS_STD_HANDLE_INFO
        {
            union
            {
                ULONG Flags;
                struct
                {
                    ULONG StdHandleState : 2; // PS_STD_HANDLE_STATE
                    ULONG PseudoHandleMask : 3; // PS_STD_*
                } s;
            };
            ULONG StdHandleSubsystemType;
        } PS_STD_HANDLE_INFO, * PPS_STD_HANDLE_INFO;
        typedef struct _CLIENT_ID
        {
            HANDLE UniqueProcess;
            HANDLE UniqueThread;
        } CLIENT_ID, * PCLIENT_ID;
    
        typedef struct _SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION
        {
            PVOID TransferAddress; // Entry point
            ULONG ZeroBits;
            SIZE_T MaximumStackSize;
            SIZE_T CommittedStackSize;
            ULONG SubSystemType;
            union
            {
                struct
                {
                    USHORT SubSystemMinorVersion;
                    USHORT SubSystemMajorVersion;
                } s1;
                ULONG SubSystemVersion;
            } u1;
            union
            {
                struct
                {
                    USHORT MajorOperatingSystemVersion;
                    USHORT MinorOperatingSystemVersion;
                } s2;
                ULONG OperatingSystemVersion;
            } u2;
            USHORT ImageCharacteristics;
            USHORT DllCharacteristics;
            USHORT Machine;
            BOOLEAN ImageContainsCode;
            union
            {
                UCHAR ImageFlags;
                struct
                {
                    UCHAR ComPlusNativeReady : 1;
                    UCHAR ComPlusILOnly : 1;
                    UCHAR ImageDynamicallyRelocated : 1;
                    UCHAR ImageMappedFlat : 1;
                    UCHAR BaseBelow4gb : 1;
                    UCHAR ComPlusPrefer32bit : 1;
                    UCHAR Reserved : 2;
                } s3;
            } u3;
            ULONG LoaderFlags;
            ULONG ImageFileSize;
            ULONG CheckSum;
        } SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION, * PSECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION;
        typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA
        {
            ULONG Length;
            BOOLEAN Initialized;
            HANDLE SsHandle;
            LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
            LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
            LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
            PVOID EntryInProgress;
            BOOLEAN ShutdownInProgress;
            HANDLE ShutdownThreadId;
        } PEB_LDR_DATA, * PPEB_LDR_DATA;
        typedef struct _PEB
        {
            BOOLEAN InheritedAddressSpace;
            BOOLEAN ReadImageFileExecOptions;
            BOOLEAN BeingDebugged;
            union
            {
                BOOLEAN BitField;
                struct
                {
                    BOOLEAN ImageUsesLargePages : 1;
                    BOOLEAN IsProtectedProcess : 1;
                    BOOLEAN IsImageDynamicallyRelocated : 1;
                    BOOLEAN SkipPatchingUser32Forwarders : 1;
                    BOOLEAN IsPackagedProcess : 1;
                    BOOLEAN IsAppContainer : 1;
                    BOOLEAN IsProtectedProcessLight : 1;
                    BOOLEAN IsLongPathAwareProcess : 1;
                } s1;
            } u1;
    
            HANDLE Mutant;
    
            PVOID ImageBaseAddress;
            PPEB_LDR_DATA Ldr;
            PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters;
            PVOID SubSystemData;
            PVOID ProcessHeap;
        } PEB, * PPEB;
    
        typedef struct _TEB
        {
            NT_TIB NtTib;
    
            PVOID EnvironmentPointer;
            CLIENT_ID ClientId;
            PVOID ActiveRpcHandle;
            PVOID ThreadLocalStoragePointer;
            PPEB ProcessEnvironmentBlock;
        } TEB, * PTEB;
    
    #define NtCurrentPeb()            (NtCurrentTeb()->ProcessEnvironmentBlock)
    #define RtlProcessHeap()          (NtCurrentPeb()->ProcessHeap)
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
```